# Pseudorandom Functions / Pseudorandom Permutations

Tags: computational-complexity

I'm reading Yao's unpredictability -> pseudorandomness construction
and Goldreich/levin's pseudorandom permutation -> pseudorandom generator construction.

My question is:

is there a direct way to show that:

given a pseudorandom function, we can construct a pseudorandom permutation out of it?

[or is this question open]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the celebrated Luby Rackoff result.

Comment: This answer should be expanded if it's to be useful to OP or anyyone else.

Comment: Luby, Michael; Rackoff, Charles (April 1988), "How to Construct Pseudorandom Permutations from Pseudorandom Functions", SIAM Journal on Computing 17 (2): 373–386, http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0217022

Answer (score 1):

To expand very slightly upon @Steve's words of wisdom, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher